# Android + DropboxSync startLink

Tags: java, android, dropbox

I want create app with sync to dropbox, but i have an error.

Who can help fix error:

```
253-253/com.shvedchenko.skleroshop W/com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity: There are multiple apps registered for the AuthActivity URI scheme (db-aaat0ujhbfgnn98).  Another app may be trying to  impersonate this app, so authentication will be disabled.
```

i have this error when i call:

```
mDbxAcctMgr.startLink((Activity)this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);
```

My AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAuthActivity" />
<activity
    android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="db-d53t0ujht25nn98" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<service
    android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:label="Dropbox Sync" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Thx!

Comment: Based on the error message, my guess would be that there are two versions of your app installed on the device/emulator. Is that true?

Comment: Thx you again:) You are right. I have tried now at home on another emulator and all works fine!Thx