# There are multiple apps registered for the AuthActivity URI scheme - Dropbox sync issue on Android

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Sorry for my poor English and the fact I am a newbie on Android development.

I'm developping an Android app which should send data to the datastore of Dropbox. My problem is, when my code is getting this line:

```
mAccountManager.startLink(DropboxHelper.this,REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);
```

Then my logcat send me the message below:

```
10-19 10:40:32.411: W/com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity(28381): There are multiple     
apps registered for the AuthActivity URI scheme (db-qeojdcjk0dkkswc).  Another app may be     
trying to  impersonate this app, so authentication will be disabled.
```

The closer explanation I have found is this one:
[Android + DropboxSync startLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592959/android-dropboxsync-startlink)

But the comments have not helped me.

Here my code :

```
public class DropboxHelper extends ActionBarActivity {

    // *** Objects and APP_KEY + APP_SECRET are instantiate here ***

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dropbox_activity);


        // Set up the account manager
        mAccountManager = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

        mUnlinkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.unlink_button);
        mUnlinkButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        // Button to link to Dropbox
        mLinkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.link_button);
        mLinkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if ( mAccountManager.getLinkedAccount() == null )
                    mAccountManager.startLink(DropboxHelper.this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(DropboxHelper.this, "Connection déjà établie, vous pouvez vous déconnecter si vous le souhaitez", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    mUnlinkButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }
        });

        mUnlinkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mAccountManager.unlink();
                Toast.makeText(DropboxHelper.this, "Déconnecté", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        // Set up the datastore manager
        if (mAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount()) {
            try {
                // Use Dropbox datastores
                mDatastoreManager = DbxDatastoreManager.forAccount(mAccountManager.getLinkedAccount());
                mLinkButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } catch (DbxException.Unauthorized e) {
                System.out.println("Account was unlinked remotely");
            }
        }
        if (mDatastoreManager == null) {
            // Account isn't linked yet, use local datastores
            mDatastoreManager = DbxDatastoreManager.localManager(mAccountManager);
            // Show link button
            mLinkButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                account = mAccountManager.getLinkedAccount();
                try {
                    // Migrate any local datastores to the linked account
                    mDatastoreManager.migrateToAccount(account);
                    // Now use Dropbox datastores
                    mDatastoreManager = DbxDatastoreManager.forAccount(account);
                    // Hide link button
                    mLinkButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } catch (DbxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // Link failed or was cancelled by the user
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }



    }

}
```

I can't figure out How to solve this issue, I really thank you If you can help me.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generally means you have more than one app installed using the same app key. Often, this can happen if you have, for example, a sample app from the SDK as well as the app you're developing installed on the same device (or virtual device) using your app key. The solution is just to uninstall one of the apps, or use a different app key in one of them.